# A nice overview (and maybe derivation) of the Poincaré transformations of the Vector Spherical Harmonics

Tags: research-level, specific-reference, group-representations, poincare-symmetry, spherical-harmonics

With $Y_{lm}(\vartheta,\varphi)$ being the Spherical Harmonics and $z_l^{(j)}(r)$ being the Spherical Bessel functions ($j=1$), Neumann functions ($j=2$) or Hankel functions ($j=3,4$) defining $$\psi_{lm}^{(j)}(r,\vartheta,\varphi)=z_l^{(j)}(r)Y_{lm}(\vartheta,\varphi),$$ what are representations of the Poincaré transformations applied to the Vector Spherical Harmonics

$$\vec L_{lm}^{(j)} = \vec\nabla \psi_{lm}^{(j)},\\ \vec M_{lm}^{(j)} = \vec\nabla\times\vec r \psi_{lm}^{(j)},\\ \vec N_{lm}^{(j)} = \vec\nabla\times\vec M_{lm}^{(j)}$$

? Does any publication cover all Poincaré-transformations, i.e. not only translations and rotations but also Lorentz boosts? I'd prefer one publication covering all transformations at once due to the different normalizations sometimes used.

Comment: disclaimer: I also asked this at [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89955/a-nice-overview-and-maybe-derivation-of-the-poincare-transformations-of-the-vec)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Poincaré group is in the fact that it is not compact. That's why this question is non-trivial. Though, properly formulated search gives few papers on this topic. Try to find the answer in this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0507056 . The paper itself may be not that interesting, but there is a nice introduction with a number of useful references.